# Having trouble outputting decimal approximations; Python 2 rounds division to 0 or 1

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, python-2.x, approximation

So I've decided to make a hypergeometric distribution calculator (probability and statistics stuff).  The problem is that the output will always be between 0 and 1.  So Python rounds down to 0 or up to 1 depending on the output value.

Here's my code

```
from combinatorics import combination
from combinatorics import permutation
from factorial import factorial
from decimal import Decimal

#Hypergeometric and Binomial Distributions!



def hypergeometric(N, n, r, k):
    hyper = (combination(r, k) * combination(N - r, n - k))/(combination(N, n))
    return hyper

pop = int(raw_input("What is the size of the population? "))
draws = int(raw_input("How many draws were there? "))
spop = int(raw_input("What is the smaller population? "))
success = int(raw_input("How many successes were there? "))

print Decimal(hypergeometric(pop, draws, spop, success))
```

I've tried importing the decimal module, but I'm not really sure if I'm using it correctly or if that's even what it's there for.  Any help would be awesome!

Edit: As an example, when I set N = 15, n = 6, r = 5, and k = 3, it rounds the answer to 0.  I would like it instead to print the proper answer: .2397802398.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the division returns a float instead of an integer (as all input variables are integers):

```
def hypergeometric(N, n, r, k):
    return 1.0 * combination(r, k) * combination(N - r, n - k) / combination(N, n)
```

**Alternative**: I assume you're using Python < 3 (otherwise this issue wouldn't have come up in the first place). Then you could do

```
from __future__ import division
```

which will make `/` the floating division, whereas `//` returns integers if given integers. Just put this `import` at the top of your source file, and you won't have to change your other code.

Comment: Thank you!  This did the trick, though now I need to work on rounding the answer to something a little more manageable.

Comment: @IvanKelber: for that you can use `round` or similar

Comment: You know there's `round`? http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round However, I would keep all the precision you have and only round in the output, using format strings such as `"%.3f"`, for example.